# Sort a list of one value dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have data:

```
{'foo': [{1: 55}, {'c': 43}], 'bar': [{1: 43}, {'c': 40}]}
```

I wanna sort the dictionaries inside the foo and bar by its values:

```
{'foo': [{'c': 43}, {1: 55}], ...}
```

I dont wanna sort the 'foo' and 'bar'.

Is there an easy way yo do this? Sorry if I make mistake in writing the dicts/lists. Thanks

Comment: Just sort them, what's the problem?

Comment: It will probally sort by the key, not value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way. `sorted` accepts a `key` argument which accepts an anonymous `lambda` function. Since each dictionary only has one key/value, you can list your values and select the first.

```
d = {'foo': [{1: 55}, {'c': 43}], 'bar': [{1: 43}, {'c': 40}]}

res = {k: sorted(v, key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]) for k, v in d.items()}

# {'bar': [{'c': 40}, {1: 43}], 'foo': [{'c': 43}, {1: 55}]}
```

Comment: I dont wanna sort the 'foo' and 'bar'.

Comment: 'foo' and 'bar' are *not* being sorted. Dictionaries are not ordered. Your input dictionary also has no order. Just because it is represented as such when you instantiate or print it, does not mean it is ordered.

Comment: @jpp Why we are doing `list(x.values())[0]` I mean why we are using 0th index here ?

Comment: @Shashank `x` is a dictionary with exactly one element, so `list(x.values())[0]` will get all the values of the dictionary and use the first one of it (which is the only one).

Comment: @poke Thanks, so in this case when it will be working for `foo` then our key will be 55 and 43, since in single dict there is only 1 value.

Comment: @Shashank Exactly, so those 55 and 43 will be used as the key for the items in the `foo` list, and `sorted()` will sort by that.

Answer (score 2):

Then tell it to sort by the value:

```
>>> x={'foo': [{1: 55}, {'c': 43}], 'bar': [{1: 43}, {'c': 40}]}
>>> for a in x: x[a].sort(key=lambda i: list(i.values())[0])
>>> x
{'bar': [{'c': 40}, {1: 43}], 'foo': [{'c': 43}, {1: 55}]}
```

Note since it's a dict, you have to retrieve all values, convert to list, and take first index. Probably not the best sturcture to sort.

Comment: I just noticed a difference in the answers - I rather use the built in list `sort`, rather than `sorted` to regenerate a list (I assumed OP wants in place).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to kabanus' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49220486) (which uses `O(len(x))` `dict` lookup), this is an approach that use [`dict` values view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

```python
x={'a': [{1: 55}, {'c': 43}], 'b': [{1: 43}, {'c': 40}]}
for a in x.values(): a.sort(key=lambda i: list(i.values())[0])
print(x)
```

prints

```python
{'a': [{'c': 43}, {1: 55}], 'b': [{'c': 40}, {1: 43}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcrBCoQgFEDRfV/xdipENFQboS8JF6@pSMbRUGcwxG83N7W8nHucfje6yzmMkSDhMMUXh2FINUTyLt13SdRA5ptKP9QmkarNWECQGkLzR/VbHWUcsHHGevpZz1Hhd17KwEFJ56l8Lja1glWHldrTwHK@AA)

---

I have not measured the performance of this method, but I expect it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
data={'foo': [{1: 55}, {'c': 43}], 'bar': [{1: 43}, {'c': 40}]}

print({i:sorted(j,key=lambda x:list(x.values())) for i,j in data.items()})
```

output:

```
{'foo': [{'c': 43}, {1: 55}], 'bar': [{'c': 40}, {1: 43}]}
```